# Closed questions listed as "Possibly related"?

Tags: support, feature-request

When looking at a question, at the right I see related ones. But often folling one of the links leads me to closed questions, and I understand that that means that the question isn't (very) relevant. Why show them here? Perhaps give an option to "Repeat search, with closed questions included" or "Show all related questions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the closed questions were closed because they were duplicates of a question that is related, but which doesn't show up on the right. (The "related questions" selection is automatic and doesn't always work right.) So we should at least include the closed questions which were closed because they were duplicates.

Comment: I assumed so much on the "related questions" selection, my compliments to whoever did that (it works very well AFAICS). Perhaps replace the closed ones by their dupliquees (invented a new word right there ;-) in that mix? Questions that are closed are, well, questionable.